# Trying to open .txt file and check if username exists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing a username/password program for class using Python 3.5, and everything works really well, except for this section. The code is supposed to open the .txt file (or create one if it doesn't exist), then check if the username you entered is already within the file. Currently, it appears to be reading a blank list ("[ ]") and basically doesn't see anything to check, therefore it accepts the username although it DOES exist in the file if you open it in the Windows file browser.

**Here is what the username function looks like:**

```
def registerNewUsername():
    checker = 0
    while(checker == 0):
        usernameInput = input("Please enter a username.\n")
        usernameInput.strip()
        usernameExists = False

        try:
            f = open("loginInfo.txt", "a+")
            userDataEntry = f.readlines()
            f.close()
        except:
            print("Something went wrong!")

        listLines = []
        for eachLine in listLines:
            entry = eachLine.split()
            keep = entry[0]
            listLines.append(keep)
        print(listLines)

        if(usernameInput in userDataEntry):
            print("This username already exists. Try again.\n")
            usernameExists = True
            checker = 0
        if("@" in usernameInput and ".edu" in usernameInput and usernameExists == False):
            print("\nUsername Accepted\n")
            checker = 1
       else:
            print("You need to include @ and .edu in your username. Try again.\n")
            checker = 0

    return usernameInput
```

**Here is what the function that CREATES the user/pass list (after the username and password are approved):**

```
def saveData(passwordInput, usernameInput):
    userDataEntry = usernameInput + " " + passwordInput + "\n"
    fileObject = open('loginInfo.txt', 'a')
    fileObject.write(userDataEntry)
    fileObject.close()
```

**The login function, however, does definitely read the list and can use the data inside, so perhaps there's something missing that is present in this function?**

```
def loginExisting():
    userDataEntry = open('loginInfo.txt', 'r')
    listLines = userDataEntry.readlines()
    userDataEntry.close()

    userDict = {}

    for eachLine in listLines:
        entry = eachLine.split()
        username = entry[0]
        password = entry[1]
        userDict[username] = password

    checker = 0
    while(checker == 0):
        print("\nYou've registered already? (OwO) Okay then!\n")
        usernameInput = input("Please enter your username:")
        passwordInput = input("Please enter your password:")


        if(usernameInput in userDict):
            if(userDict[usernameInput] == passwordInput):
                print("\nLogin successful!\nWelcome back,", usernameInput)
                checker = 1

            else:
                print("Password is incorrect. Try again.")
                checker = 0

        else:
            print("Username does not exist. Try again.")
            checker = 0

    nextStep = int(input("\nWould you like to:\n1.) Exit\n2.) Log out and return to menu\n\n"))
    if(nextStep == 1):
        print("\nGoodbye!")

    if(nextStep == 2):
        print("\nReturning to menu...\n")

        return nextStep
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more about what isn't working? What is your desired output, and what are you getting? Is it crashing?

Comment: Basically the code just needs to verify the username isn't already in the file and then move on. The print statement is just to check that it is correctly opening and reading the txt file. Right now it prints an empty list, but the txt file contains "username@blah.edu password3" (with the space). If I try to input the same username, it accepts it instead of taking the "This username already exists. Try again.\n" route that restarts the username registration process. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because in the `registerNewUsername` function, you run `usernameInput.strip()` without assigning it to anything. If you don't assign the result back to the variable or a different variable, nothing happens. Try running it again changing the `usernameInput.strip()` line to `usernameInput = usernameInput.strip()`.